# Extracting a .DAT file

Tags: android, java, decompile, apk

I want to extract a chunk of text available in an android app. 
I disassembled the APK and found a .DAT file which seems to carry the text I'm looking for (the file was inside the directory res/raw/).

Does anybody have an idea of how to decompile this .DAT file and extract the text?

One tip: Judging from the many .java files in the extracted APK, it's safe to assume we are dealing with JAVA here.

Here's the file I am trying to decompile: https://www.dropbox.com/s/04pgp6ettuiyj6u/genesis_1.dat?dl=1

Answer (score 1):

According to the output of the `file` utility it is

> Java serialization data, version 5

Which allegedly can be unpacked with [jdeserialize-like](https://code.google.com/p/jdeserialize/)
utilities.